# FernDescriptorMatch - how to use it? how it works?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, machine-learning, pattern-matching, computer-vision

How to use FERN descriptor matcher in OpenCV? Does it take as an input keypoints extracted by some algrithm (sift/surf?) or it calculates everything by itself?

edit:
I'm trying to apply it do database of images

```
fernmatcher->add(all_images, all_keypoints);
fernmatcher->train();
```

there are 20 images, in total less than 8MB, i extract keypoints using SURF. Memory usage jumps to 2.6GB and training takes who knows how long...

Answer (score 1):

FERN is not different from rest of the matchers. Here is a sample code for using FERN as Key point Descriptor Matcher.

```
int octaves= 3;
int octaveLayers=2;
bool upright=false;
double hessianThreshold=0;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1,keypoints_2;
SurfFeatureDetector detector1( hessianThreshold, octaves, octaveLayers, upright );
detector1.detect( image1, keypoints_1 );
detector1.detect( image2, keypoints_2 );
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
FernDescriptorMatcher matcher;
matcher.match(image1,keypoints_1,image2,keypoints_2,matches);
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( templat_img, keypoints_1,tempimg, keypoints_2,matches,  img_matches,Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
imshow( "Fern Matches", img_matches);
waitKey(0);
```

**But But my suggestion is use FAST which is faster compared to FERN and also FERN can be used to train a set of images with keypoints and the trained FERN can be used as classifier just like all other.*

Comment: But the problem appears when I try to train the matcher.
I try to add vector of images and vector of keypoints (matcher.add)
there are 20 images, in total ~8MB and memory usage jumps to 2.6GB - is it normal? and training seems to take a lot of time...

Comment: Hi, While using FERN or FLANN as classifier we need to give only template image and in general the training templates are of small size like i trained my FERN and FLANN with face templates of size 20K and number of templates are 900. As you said the memory increases even you released unnecessary memory. So my suggestion is please Resize your template images.One more thing Only these marchers are not enough to classify the objects.

Comment: so you are saying, that you use 900 images of size for example 100x200px each and it works reasonably well (talking about memory and CPU time)?

I have used FLANN & SURF with database of 1000 images (more or less 1024x600, 350MB) and it worked surprisingly well (the training time was maybe 70 seconds, but the matching time was about 0.1sec [as expected strongly depending on the number of keypoints detected])

Comment: Yes, and also after you asked the question I checked the FERN matcher to match two images of size 2000x2000 with surf keypoint extractor it took more than 10 min's for matching the keypoints. But where as the FLANN took less than a min. But the performance is nearly not distinguishable in terms of correct matches. Any way I also feel that only key points and matchers are not enough to describe an object for identification and recognition. For any more info please contact me.